# ReadLine seems to be taking turns around connections and sends, causing problems

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am making a server chat function in raw mode connection that handles multiple connections in order to chat about the debugging messages in my big application. It uses the list of `StreamReader` to populate with the reading streams of connections to allow people to write their text messages on the debugger network console.

I am implementing the chat function for the next version of the app, so connected clients can chat and comment about debugging messages that prints as long as the application is running.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on .NET Framework 4.7.2. As I have finished writing the chat function, it seems that when the first user has connected to the debugger, the chat looks fine, because everytime they pressed Enter, the debug message about it appears, just like:

```
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:55): Debug device 192.168.1.105 connected.
Test
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Test
Test 2
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Test 2
Debugger test
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Debugger test
```

However, as time passes, the user will be connecting to the debugger just fine, but the chat function seems to be not working for the other user until the first user talked, so it behaves as if they're taking turns for their messages to be posted.

Additionally, when the second user talked once or too much, and the first user presses Enter repeatedly, it seems that the second user's messages appear after the second keypress of Enter or the second send of the message.

Upon further debugging, I found that `ReadLine` seems to be blocking, when it should go ahead without printing a message, and going to another `StreamReader` in the next connection to allow messages to pass correctly. This means that when I resume the program after the `ReadLine` breakpoint, it won't go on until the next message is detected, and if the second user tries to talk, the breakpoint won't trigger until the first user talks.

For clarification, here's the output of both connections:

- First connection:

```
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:55): Debug device 127.0.0.1 connected.
Hello
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Hello
Test
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Test
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Hello

9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> 
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Snja

9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> 
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Sinmue

9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> 
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Sona

9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> 

9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Mnjad
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> 
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> kodkw
fds
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> fds
```

- Second connection:

```
9/9/2019 5:57 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:55): Debug device 127.0.0.1 connected.
Hello
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Hello
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> Test
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Hello
Snja
Sinmue
Sona
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105>
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Snja
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105>
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Sinmue
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105>
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Sona
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105>
Mnjad
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> Mnjad
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105>
kodkw
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 127.0.0.1> kodkw
9/9/2019 5:58 PM (RemoteDebugger.vb:70): 192.168.1.105> fds
```

The code used as part of the chat function in a big project is below:

```vb
    Public DebugPort As Integer = 3014
    Public RDebugClient As Socket
    Public DebugTCP As TcpListener
    Public DebugDevices As New List(Of Socket)
    Public dbgConns As New List(Of StreamWriter)
    Public dbgChats As New Dictionary(Of StreamReader, String)

    Sub StartRDebugThread()
        If DebugMode Then
            Dim RDebugThread As New Thread(AddressOf StartRDebugger) With {.IsBackground = True}
            RDebugThread.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub StartRDebugger()
        'Listen to a current IP address
        DebugTCP = New TcpListener(New IPAddress({0, 0, 0, 0}), DebugPort)
        DebugTCP.Start()
        Dim RStream As New Thread(AddressOf ReadAndBroadcastAsync)
        RStream.Start()
        W(DoTranslation("Debug listening on all addresses using port {0}.", currentLang), True, ColTypes.Neutral, DebugPort)

        While Not RebootRequested
            Try
                Dim RDebugStream As NetworkStream
                Dim RDebugClient As Socket
                If DebugTCP.Pending Then
                    RDebugClient = DebugTCP.AcceptSocket
                    RDebugStream = New NetworkStream(RDebugClient)
                    dbgConns.Add(New StreamWriter(RDebugStream) With {.AutoFlush = True})
                    dbgChats.Add(New StreamReader(RDebugStream), RDebugClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.Remove(RDebugClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.IndexOf(":")))
                    DebugDevices.Add(RDebugClient)
                    Wdbg("Debug device {0} connected.", RDebugClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.Remove(RDebugClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.IndexOf(":")))
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                W(DoTranslation("Error in connection: {0}", currentLang), True, ColTypes.Neutral, ex.Message)
            End Try
        End While

        DebugTCP.Stop()
        dbgConns.Clear()
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
    End Sub

    Sub ReadAndBroadcastAsync()
        While True
            For i As Integer = 0 To dbgChats.Count - 1
                Dim msg As String = dbgChats.Keys(i).ReadLine()
                Wdbg("{0}> {1}", dbgChats.Values(i), msg)
            Next
        End While
    End Sub
```

What can I do? I also tried the `ReadLineAsync` function to await for it, but it doesn't change anything. If you need any further information, I will provide them.

Comment: You cannot use StreamReader.  Google "vb.net chat application" to see how other programmers did it, first hit should be good.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but why can't I use NetworkStream's StreamReader? Is it because it's very inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the chat that seems to be taking turns, by putting the read timeout to 10 milliseconds before reading.

```vb
streamnet.ReadTimeout = 10 'Seems to have fixed it
```

While the reader is timing out, it generates an exception with the SocketErrorCode being ReadTimeout, so I have surrounded the Read and all functions around it by the Try..Catch block, making up:

```vb
Try
    streamnet.Read(buff, 0, 65536)
    Dim msg As String = Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buff)
    msg = msg.Replace(vbCr, vbNullChar) 'Remove all instances of vbCr (macOS newlines) } Windows hosts are affected, too, because it uses
    msg = msg.Replace(vbLf, vbNullChar) 'Remove all instances of vbLf (Linux newlines) } vbCrLf, which means (vbCr + vbLf)
    If Not msg.StartsWith(vbNullChar) Then Wdbg("{0}> {1}", ip, msg) 'Don't post message if it starts with a null character.
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim SE As SocketException = CType(ex.InnerException, SocketException)
    If Not IsNothing(SE) And Not SE.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.TimedOut Then
        Wdbg("Error from host {0}: {1}", ip, SE.SocketErrorCode.ToString)
    End If
End Try
```

So, if you're going to make a chat server without the client running in raw text mode, use this.